# int value in database not being updated

Tags: asp.net, linq

My web page updates a table record on the server. "count" is an int variable that counts the score of a quiz. Its value is correctly displayed on the web page but the record saved in the database shows value "0" for all records.

```
int count = 0;

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

count++; // for each correct answer

} 
protected void submitScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
var check = (from i in dc.QuizTakens where (i.username ==Context.User.Identity.Name && i.SubName == "Sports" && i.Lev=="Easy")select i).SingleOrDefault();


if (check == null)
{
    QuizTaken q = new QuizTaken();
    q.SubName = "Sports";
    q.Lev = "Easy";
    q.username = Context.User.Identity.Name;
    q.score_max = count;
    dc.QuizTakens.InsertOnSubmit(q);
    dc.SubmitChanges();

 }
 }
```

The primary key of this table is SubName, Lev, QId. The entire record is added to the table but the value of score_max is always 0 even though i am able to display the correct value of score_max on the web page.

Comment: What is the value of `c` when this code is run? What happens if the record already exists? You're not updating it anywhere

Comment: i am sorry, c is "count". i have editted the code now

Comment: Where does the count come from? can you show that part of the code?

Comment: the structure is as follows:

`code`

public void page_load(...)
{
....
}

int count=0;

protected findScore_Click(...)
{
count++; //for every correct answer
}

protected submitScore_Click()
{
   // code in above question
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've shown, your `count` is just a class field, not backed by `ViewState` or other page-level storage. Which means it will be `0` on every page postback, and as that it will be written to db.

You need to store its value between page loads, most likely in `ViewState`.

Comment: i have tried both ViewState and Session in the following way:
    protected void page_load()
    {
     ViewState["score"]=0;
     ....
    }
    protected void Button1_click()
    {
      count++; //for each correct answer
      ....
      ViewState["score"]=count;
    }
    protected void submitScore_Click()
    {
      ...
      dc.score_max=System.Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["score"]);
    }
But the problem persists!

Comment: Of course it does, because you reset your `ViewState` on each `Page_Load`.

Comment: Thank you very much, saved it in my button1_click() function. let me know if you see any other thing wrong with that!